# Killing a function while runtime in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a VSCODE extension in TypeScript. In this extension I have a realy fat function, which is called very often but just the last call is interessting. So I try to kill previous calls.

my idea:

```
var test;

async funciont foo(change){
  test = new Class(change);
  test.run()
}
```

The idea is realy simply the function foo is ansynchron, that "foo" is not waiting till "run" is finish and could be called a second time while "run" is running. If foo is called a second time, it should create a new "test" to terminate the old run and start a new one. But it doesn't seem to work. Is there a Problem with my idea?

Background to implemention in vscode.
I used a Server Lanuage Example as start-project and "foo" is called by

```
documents.onDidChangeContent((change)=>{
    foo(change)
})
```

Comment: I don't understand.  What is your exact question?

Comment: You have an async function but you're not `await`ing anything. Does `run()` return a promise?

Comment: no at the end "run()" is sending information to the client

Comment: @zero298 my question is, should my idea work?
if yes, why does it seem, that it doesn't work
If no, what should I do, that it work

Comment: @peni4142 You can't "kill" calls to functions in javascript. The only way to have the previous call to `run` stop is for it to `return` or `throw`.

Comment: @ SimpleJ thank you, nice to know

Answer (score 0):

```
var test;

async funciont foo(change){
  test.stop()
  test = new Class(change);
  test.run()
}
```

and run need something like that:

```
await new Promise((resolve)=>{
                setTimeout(resolve, 0)
            })
```

"stop" is changing a booelean which let end the "run" function. The timeout give time to the thread to call "foo" function additional time